# mkdir /.gitlab-runner: permission denied running GitLab Runner in Kubernetes deployed via Helm

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to deploy the GitLab Runner (15.7.1) onto an on-premise Kubernetes cluster and getting the following error:

`PANIC: loading system ID file: saving system ID state file: creating directory: mkdir /.gitlab-runner: permission denied`

This is occurring with both the 15.7.1 image (Ubuntu?) and the alpine3.13-v15.7.1 image.  Looking at the deployment, it looks likes it should be trying to use /home/gitlab-runner, but for some reason it is trying to use root (/), which is a protected directory.

Anyone else experience this issue or have a suggestion as to what to look at?

I am using the Helm chart (0.48.0) using a copy of the images from dockerhub (simply moved into a local repository as internet access is not available from the cluster).  Connectivity to GitLab appears to be working, but the error causes the overall startup to fail.  Full logs are:

Registration attempt 4 of 30
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=33 revision=6d480948 version=15.7.1
WARNING: Running in user-mode.
WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing:
WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...

Created missing unique system ID                    system_id=r_Of5q3G0yFEVe
PANIC: loading system ID file: saving system ID state file: creating directory: mkdir /.gitlab-runner: permission denied

I have tried the 15.7.1 image, the alpine3.13-v15.7.1 image, and the gitlab-runner-ocp:amd64-v15.7.1 image and searched the values.yaml for anything relevant to the path.  Looking at the deployment template, it appears that it ought to be using /home/gitlab-runner as the directory (instead of /) [though the docs suggested it was /home].

As for "what was I expecting", of course I was expecting that it would "just work" :)

Comment: I should note that the images referenced are bitnami (e.g. bitnami/gitlab-runner) with the exception of the ocp ones ...

Comment: Was able to get it working (further) by modifying the deployment template to mount an empty volume at /.gitlab-runner, but unsure if this is appropriate.

Comment: This requirement remained true on Helm chart v0.49.0
I also found I needed to explicitly add builds_dir and environment [per gitlab-org/gitlab-runner#3511 (comment 114281106)].

Answer (score 0):

So, resolved this (and other) issues with:

1. Updated helm deployment template to mount an empty volume at /.gitlab-runner
2. [separate issue] explicitly added builds_dir and environment [per gitlab-org/gitlab-runner#3511 (comment 114281106)].

These two steps appeared to be sufficient to get the Helm chart deployment working.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create and mount the emptyDir (in case you are creating gitlab-runner with kubernetes manifest `*.yml` file):

```
    volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: gitlab-runner
    volumeMounts:
      - name: gitlab-runner
        mountPath: /.gitlab-runner
```

> -------------------- OR --------------------

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: root-gitlab-runner
        mountPath: /.gitlab-runner
    volumes:
      - name: root-gitlab-runner
        emptyDir:
          medium: "Memory"
```